# AngularJS filtering over embedded property

Tags: angularjs, filtering

I have a contact objects and in this contact objects there are account objects included:

> vm.contacts.accounts

and each account does have an accountNumber. Now I want to filter the contacts over an accountnumber.
I have tried it like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechnungsnummer eingeben" data-ng-model="searchedAccountNumber" /> 
    <br />
    <div data-ng-repeat="contact in vm.contacts | filter:  { accounts: [{ accountNumber: searchedAccountNumber }] }"
```

but it does not work. Does anyone have an idea how I can do the filtering?

Comment: try `filter:  ( accounts: [{ accountNumber: searchedAccountNumber }] )`

Comment: thanks for the response, sorrily still nothing is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a filter function:

```
//Controller
function hasSearchedAccountNumber(contact) {
  var accounts = contact.accounts;
  var accountHasAccountNumber = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
    //For an exact match, could do a partial match as well)
    if (accounts[i].accountNumber === $scope.searchedAccountNumber) {
      accountHasAccountNumber = true;
      break; //If one account has the number, it's not needed to look for other accounts 
    }
  }
  return accountHasAccountNumber;
}
```

In your html:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="contact in vm.contacts | filter: hasSearchedAccountNumber(contact);"></div>
```